# Scale negative xticks to different scale than positive x ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

is this possible?

I have a barchart representing the difference between two dataframe columns divided by the original dataframe column

```
        difference = (df - full_df)/full_df
```

I then plot the difference

```
    difference.plot(kind='barh',color =  ['r' if x > 0 else 'b' for x in difference.values]).\
        set_yticklabels([str(tick)[:45] for tick in difference.index])
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.gca().set_title('Selected minus full feature set averages divided by full', fontsize=30)
    axs[1].yaxis.tick_right()
    axs[1].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
    axs[1].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
    plt.yticks(fontsize=23)        
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Most the positive x numbers are going to be in the range of 0 < x < 10. All of the negative numbers should between -1 < x < 0. Is there a way to set the xtick intervals below zero to .1 (or something like that) and the xtick intervals above 0 to 1 so the x axis would look like:

```
 [-1,-.9,-.8,-.7,-.6,-.5,-.4,-.3,-.2,-.1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, to inf] ?
```

Comment: You mean `plt.xticks(<your list of values>)`?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question correctly, but I think are looking for a plot with negative x and positive x on different scales, but taking up the same amount of space.  I think the easiest solution would be to scale your x negative axis data so that it fits well with the y axis data and then relabel the ticks on their original scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# original data
data_x = x = [-1,-.9,-.8,-.7,-.6,-.5,-.4,-.3,-.2,-.1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
data_y = y = range(len(data_x))

# scale negative x values
x_mod =[i*10 if i < 0 else i for i in x]

# draw plots  
with sns.axes_style('whitegrid'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(5,8))

    # unscaled
    ax1 = ax[0]
    ax2 = ax[1]
    ax1.plot(data_x, data_y)
    ax1.vlines(0, 0, 20, color='black') # mark x = 0 
    ax1.set_title('unscaled data')

    # scaled
    ax2.plot(x_mod, data_y)

    # fix the xticks and their labeling
    xticks = list(np.concatenate([np.arange(-1,0, 0.2),np.arange(0,11,2)]))
    xtick_locs  = list(np.concatenate([np.arange(-1,0, 0.2) *10, np.arange(0,11,2)]))

    ax2.set(xticks=xtick_locs, xticklabels = xticks)
    ax2.vlines(0, 0, 20, color='black')
    ax2.set_title('scaled data')
```

[image]

Comment: What is `sns`??

Comment: `sns` was supposed to be `seaborn`, thank you for editing!